# Can you make money from a flying blog or YouTube channel with a PPL?

Tags: faa-regulations, ppl, compensation

Is it legal for a private pilot to blog about flights, or record them and post the videos online, and monetize the content using ads?

Comment: I would say so. Check out Mojo Grip on youtube.

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/79960/does-the-faa-consider-flights-that-generate-content-for-profitable-youtube-chann

Comment: Related: [FAA Assistant Chief Counsel for Regulations interpretation for taking photos to be sold later](https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/agc/practice_areas/regulations/interpretations/data/interps/2010/Perry_2010_Legal_Interpretation.pdf). This letter is discussed [here](http://www.askacfi.com/30153/as-a-private-pilot-is-it-legal-to-film-a-flight-with-intention-to-post-on-youtube-etc-for-compensation.htm).